# found = False. Why it is written in the code?

Tags: python, cgi

This code takes the data from html and searches in afile.If a search is found it makes a print on web browser. Now i have query regarding why the found = False is written after b.append() line. b'coz if we dont write it prints all the data in the file on the web browser

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi

def get_search():

    found = False

    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    Fname = form.getvalue('firstname', '')
    Lname = form.getvalue('lastname', '')
    Age = form.getvalue('age', 0)
    Gender = form.getvalue('gender', '')


    f = open("/tmp/abcd.txt","r")
    b = []
    for line in f:
        temp = line.split()

        Fsearch = temp[0]
        Lsearch = temp[1]
        Asearch = temp[2]
        Gsearch = temp[3]

        if Fname and Fname.lower() in Fsearch.lower():
            found = True

        if Lname and Lname.lower() in Lsearch.lower():
            found = True

        if Age and Age == Asearch:
            found = True

        if Gender and Gender in Gsearch:
            found = True
        if found:
            b.append(line)
        found = False
    f.close()
    print "Content-type:text/html\n"
    if len(b) == 0:
        print "No records found"
    else:
        for each in b:
             print each

get_search()
```

Comment: No matter a search is found or not, the line will be printed out as found is always true if there is no found=False in behind. And if you do not give found any value, the program may encounter an error at the first loop as found is not defined when any of the keywords is not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is there to simply renew the `found` variable to `False` at the end of each loop pass. This is done because the new iteration should start with `found = False` (by default at the beginning of each search). Otherwise, once one `line` sets `found` to `True` it will always stay `True` (for the following `line`s, which is wrong).

Actually, from my point of view it is better to put such variables at the beginning of the loop, as a kind of initialization part. (But that's a matter of taste and 'good practices' which significantly differ among people)